# displayDialogAsync - how to include request header to a URL?

Tags: office-js

I have a site that expects a custom request header like this:

```
GET https://example.com
AuthToken: mYCustomT0k3nHere
```

How do I send such `AuthToken` header when opening this site from OfficeJS ?

```
function openMySite() {
     var authToken = "mYCustomT0k3nHere";
     //how to send authToken when requesting mysite.com ?
     Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://example.com');
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you do this using ```fetch```? Then load the html you receive as a response into the dialog? This way you could send the token as a header in the fetch request request.

Comment: Where to use the fetch @NincaTirtil ? All I know is calling that displayDialogAsync and the site pops up. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I was thinking you want to display an html page, but looks like you want to open the whole site in the dialog, with all its functionality. My suggestion would work for getting one string response and then load it as an html and display it. It wouldn't work for a whole website. You would use the fetch to get the html string and then display it in the dialog.

Comment: Do you have a sample code for this @NincaTirtil ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customize the Request object for the URL that you pass to `displayDialogAsync`. A possible workaround is to have the page that you pass to `displayDialogAsync` run JavaScript that makes an ajax call with a custom header. Search for "how to attach custom request header with javascript".

Comment: Do you have an example for this workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use `fetch` with headers:

```js
let token = "mYCustomT0k3nHere";
let url = 'https://example.com';
let url_obj = {
  validateHttpsCertificates: true,
  method: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
  },
  muteHttpExceptions: true
}
let response = await fetch(url, url_obj);
if (!response.ok) {
  // throw error.
  let err = new Error(response.statusText);
  throw err;
}
// try to parse and return the content of http response.
let resp = await response.json();
return resp;
```

Comment: Where do you call `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync` after this ?